# gpg importing public key

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, gnupg

I'm trying to follow this: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Step_by_Step_Guide/s1-gnupg-import.html to import a `key.asc` using `gpg --import key.asc`, so that I can try to verify it, but I get the error:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

How can I resolve this? (Easy way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way? Get whoever provided you the key file to give you a valid one, because they one they gave you is damaged or was generated incorrectly.

Without seeing the key itself, nobody will be able to give you more information than that, short of a lot of guesses of ways that the key could be invalid or a lot of instruction on the format of OpenPGP keys sufficient for you to recognize the problem with the key yourself.